# Matlab - creating psd with right scaling

Tags: matlab, audio

I want to analyze an audiodata (.wav with pcm, 32k as sampling rate) and create the psd of it with the axes Sxx (watts/hertz not db) and f (hertz).

So I would start by reading out the audiodata with:

```
[x,fs]=audioread('test.wav');
```

After this I'm having some problems because I dont really know how to proceed and also Matlab always tells me that psd functions won't be supported in the future and that I should use pwelch.. (also tried to build the autocorr and afterwards use fourier to get to the Sxx but it didn't work out really well)

So could anybody tell me how I can get from my vector x to a vector with the psdvalues in watts/hertz and plot it afterwards?

very grateful for every kind of help! :)

**Update1**: Yes I did read the documentation of pwelch but I'm afraid my english is too bad to understand it completly.
So if I use the psd documentation:

```
nfft = 2^nextpow2(length(x));
Pxx = abs(fft(x,nfft)).^2/length(x)/fs;
Hpsd = dspdata.psd(Pxx(1:length(Pxx)/2),'fs',fs);  
plot(Hpsd)
```

I'm able to get the plot in db with the peak at the right frequency. (I dont know how dspdata.psd work though)

I tried out:

```
[Pyy,f]=pwelch(x,fs)
plot(Pyy)
```

this gives me a non db-scale but the peak is at the wrong frequency

**Update 2**: 
First of all, thanks a lot for your detailed answer! At the moment I'm working on my matlabskills as well as my english language but all the specific technical terms give me a hard time..
When using your example of pwelch on a wav-data with a clear frequency of 1khz, the plot shows me the peak at round about 0.14, could it maybe still be a special-scaled x-axis?

If I try it this way:

```
[y,fs]=audioread('test.wav');
N=length(y);
bin_vals=0:N-1;
fax_Hz= bin_vals*fs/N;
N_2=ceil(N/2);
Y=fft(y);
pyy=Y.*conj(Y);
plot(fax_Hz(1:N_2),pyy(1:N_2))
```

the result seems right (is this way correct?), but I still need some time to search for a proper way to display the y-axis in W/Hz, since I dont know how the audiosignal was created.

**Update 3**:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=33803229773204653857
This wav file should have a dominant frequency at 1khz with a duration of 3 seconds and a sampling frequency of 44100Hz. (If I plot the data received from audioread the oscillation seems reasonable)

with

```
[y,fs]=audioread('1khz.wav');
[pyy,f]=pwelch(y,fs);
plot(f,pyy)
```

I get a peak at 0.14 on the x-axis.

if I use

```
[y,fs]=audioread('1khz.wav');
[pyy,f]=pwelch(y,[],[],[],fs);
plot(f,pyy)
```

instead, the peak is at the 1000. Is this way right? And how could I interpret the difference scaling on the y-axis? (pwelch vs. square of abs)
I also wanted to ask if it is possible to get a flat psd of awgn in matlab? (since you just have finite elements I don't know to get there)

Thanks again for your detailed support!

**Update 4**
@A.Donda
So I have a new Problem for which I think it is probably necessary to go a bit more into detail. So my plan is basically to do the following:

1. Read and Audiodata ([y,fs]) and generate white Noise with a certain SNR ([n,fs])
2. Generate a Filter H which shapes the PSD(y) similiar to the PSD(n)
3. Generate an inverse Filter G=H^(-1) which reverts the effect of H.

My problem is that with using pwelch, the resulting vectorlength of pyy is way smaller than the vectorlength of y. Since my Filter  is determined by P=sqrt(pnn/pyy), I can't multiply fft(y)*H and therefore get no results.
Do you know any help for this Problem? 
Or is there a way to go back from a PSD (Welch estimated) to a normal signal (like an inverse function for pwelch)?

Comment: To use `pwelch` is good advice. Have you read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html)?

Comment: Answered in my Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you have from the `psd` documentation, you compute a psd estimate yourself, then put it into a `dspdata.psd` container and plot it. What `dspdata.psd` data does here for you is basically compute the frequency axis and provide it to the `plot` command, nothing more. You get a plot of the spectral density estimate, but that's the one you compute yourself using `fft`, which is the simplest and worst psd estimate you can get, a so-called periodogram.

<s>Your use of `pwelch` is almost correct, you just forgot to use the frequency axis information in your plot.</s>

```
[Pyy,f]=pwelch(x,fs)
plot(f,Pyy)
```

should give you the peak at the correct frequency.

Your use of `pwelch` is almost correct, but you have to give the sampling frequency as the 5th argument, and then use the frequency axis information in your plot.

```
[Pyy,f]=pwelch(y,[],[],[],fs);
plot(f,Pyy)
```

should give you the peak at the correct frequency.

What `pwelch` gives you is the spectral density of the signal over Hz. Correct axis labels would therefore be

```
xlabel('frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('psd (1/Hz)')
```

The signal you give `pwelch` is a pure sequence of numbers without physical dimensions. By specifying the sampling rate, the time axis gets a physical unit, s, therefore the resulting frequency is in Hz and the density is in 1/Hz. But still your time series values have no physical dimension, and therefore the density cannot be related to something like W. Has your audiosignal been obtained by a calibrated A/D converter? If yes, you should be able to relate your data to a physical dimension and units, but that's a nontrivial step.

On a personal note, I'd really advise you to brush up on your English, because using software, especially programming interfaces, without properly understanding the documentation is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thanks alot! I wrote an "update2" and would be deeply grateful for further information

Comment: @klaus, I can't think of a reason to estimate the psd simply using the Fourier transform squared and not a proper spectral estimator like `pwelch`. If the peak is not where you expect it, it is possible that you (or the wav file) specified the wrong sampling rate. If there is a clearly dominant frequency, plot the signal itself, zoom in, and see how long a period is; does this match what you assume about sampling rate and dominant frequency? If you can post the audio file itself, I can take a look at it.

Comment: Regarding physical units, I really think its impossible unless you know the characteristics of the recording / sampling / digitizing device.

Comment: @klaus Ah..., I just adopted the calling syntax for `pwelch` from your question and didn't check it. Note to self: Never post code you haven't checked! ;-) With your last update, everything should be OK. I'll edit my answer, too.

Comment: Thanks :) I think with all the support you give in this board its unavoidable to make a few mistakes. Do you perhaps know the answers to my other questions as well? (different scaling interpretation and how to get a flat psd of white gaussion noise when its created with a finite amount of values)

Comment: @klaus, the `pwelch` and the simple Fourier-based estimate differ in more than just scaling; simply put, the former gives a smoothed version of the latter, which inevitable makes peaks smaller. But as I said before, `pwelch` is a proper spectral estimator and simple Fourier-based is not, so just trust the latter. If you want to learn more, read about spectral estimation, e.g. in Wikipedia; important keywords are "periodogram" and "modified periodogram". Or see https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/spectral-analysis.html

Comment: The `pwelch` psd estimate of white noise is flat in principle, it is just very noisy. In order to make it flatter (reduce noise) you can increase the smoothing mentioned before. The important parameter to `pwelch` is the second one, `window`, which specifies the window length. By default it is chosen such there are 8 windows (overlapping by 50%), approximately the length of your time series divided by 4.5. Use a smaller window size (e.g. 1000) to get a smoother psd estimate.

Comment: update4 thanks again for your endurance and help. I hope I can finish after this one :)

Comment: @klaus, for a new problem you need a new question